# Excel date/product count to specified limit

Tags: excel

Column A "Sales Dates", Column B "=A2-A1" for "Date Diff", Column C "Customer Name", Column D "Item", Column E "Items Ordered Count"

My issue is I have to do a running 30 day total for each customer to see that specific items are not being ordered above "x" number within any 30-day period.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I guess I could do it the pain way by having a column with everyday of the year then just sum the last 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

I may not be fully understanding your question, but I don't think you can do what you ask in excel.  This might be a situation where a database that can do SQL might come in handy.

The best I can come up with in excel is a Pivot Table, with the customers as rows, dates as columns (group by month), and sum of Items Ordered in the data area.  Then conditional format the data area to highlight values > your limit.

Perhaps if you provide some sample data & output I can come up with something more like what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The formula would look something like this:

```
{=SUM(IF((A$2:A2>=A2-29)*(D$2:D2=D2),E$2:E2,0))}
```

It should be entered into cell F2 and copied down to the last row of your data. I pasted in a test spreadsheet below so you can see where things go (sorry for the formatting--hopefully it will look better if you paste it into Excel).

IMPORTANT: This is an array formula, so after you type in the formula (and **don't** type in the braces {} when you do), you must press Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of just Enter (see [this link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HA010872901033.aspx) for more details).

What does the formula do? It does two loops:

- First, it loops through all the Sales Dates from the beginning of the log to the current row and checks if each date is between the date of the current row and 29 days earlier (which makes a 30-day window). (By "current row" I mean the row where the formula is located.)
- Second, it loops through all the Items from the beginning of the log to the current row and checks if there is a match with the Item of the current row.

For any row where *both* checks are true (the "*" in the formula does an "and" operation), Items Ordered Count is added to the sum, otherwise zero is added to the sum. So, when it's finished, you have a count for each row of how many orders there were in the past 30 days for that item.

HTH,

-Dan

```
Sales Dates Date Diff   Customer Name   Item    Items Ordered Count 30-Day Count
1/1/2009    0   dfsadf  11336   70  70
1/2/2009    1   asdfd   10218   121 121
1/3/2009    1   fsdfjkfl    10942   101 101
1/6/2009    3   slkdjflsk   13710   80  80
1/7/2009    1   slkdjls 10480   127 127
1/9/2009    2   sdjjf   11336   143 213
1/11/2009   2   woieuriwe   11501   84  84
1/14/2009   3   owqieyurtn  10191   78  78
1/15/2009   1   weisd   10480   113 240
1/16/2009   1   woieuriwe   12024   133 133
1/17/2009   1   vkcjl   13818   125 125
1/20/2009   3   sdflkj  11336   128 341
1/23/2009   3   jnbkdl  10480   141 381
1/25/2009   2   pqcvnlz 10480   137 518
1/27/2009   2   hwodkjgfh   12878   80  80
1/28/2009   1   zjdnfg;pwlkd    10942   123 224
1/31/2009   3   zlkdjnf;psod    13173   93  93
2/2/2009    2   zlknpdodfg  11336   119 390
2/4/2009    2   zjhdfpwskjh 12004   57  57
2/5/2009    1   asdfd   10218   121 121
2/8/2009    3   fsdfjkfl    10942   101 224
2/11/2009   3   slkdjflsk   13710   80  80
2/14/2009   3   slkdjls 10480   127 405
2/16/2009   2   sdjjf   11336   143 390
2/18/2009   2   woieuriwe   11501   84  84
2/21/2009   3   owqieyurtn  10191   78  78
2/24/2009   3   weisd   10480   113 240
2/25/2009   1   woieuriwe   12024   133 133
2/27/2009   2   vkcjl   13818   125 125
2/28/2009   1   sdflkj  11336   128 390
```